# "hide" my website address/URL from Facebook google+ etc

Tags: php, cookies, social-networking

hi how can i  "hide" my website address/URL from Facebook goggle+ etc.... tracking cookies.in order to keep the privacy of the the people who browse my website ,100% of them have an account in one or more of the popular social networks.they don't want  that this website will be documented in Facebook .(and no it is not porn:)

Comment: I think tali is not talking about scrapers...

Comment: not scrapers. but it is a good reminder

Answer (score 1):

Social networks will only know if a person visits a website if either:

- The person has a browser extension installed which tells them (there is nothing you can do about this)
- The person follows a link *from* a social network (in which case the network can find out before the browser arrives on your site, so there is nothing you can do about it)
- Your site loads resources from a server controlled by the social network (such as Share links or Google Ads). Don't add such features to your site.

Comment: So I can only recommend for some of my clients to install add-on like facebook  disconnect  or Ghostery  but I can't add nothing to my website that will make the url  "disappear from the facebook  GPS" ?
ok.

Comment: Those two products, as far as I know, deal with the third case in the list above. i.e. When an author does use Google Ads / Facebook scripts / etc, they can kill them. Since, as the author, you can prevent your site from including such features in the first place, that won't help with your site.

Answer (score 0):

Just don't put "like"/"+1" buttons on your website, and neither Facebook nor Google will know their users visited your site.

Answer (score 0):

you can't hide your url, when users click on a link to facebook, google etc. 
A really good way, that facebook & co. can't get your url without a user-click is a two-click plugin like http://www.heise.de/extras/socialshareprivacy/ (the documentation is in german, but you can copy the code - it is intuitive usable)...

I'm not sure, but maybe you can also try to redirect all external links over an other site - but I can't garant that it will solve the problem ;)

Comment: I found this plugin tutorial in English too    [LINK](http://panzi.github.com/SocialSharePrivacy)     . good to know TNX! but for my website I am not going to Embed social share buttons(LIKE BUTTON) just basic simple links to sites the client himself chooses to add.  like link to his FACBOOK images gallery for example  (not hotlinking  )